# Large or small fonts on Windows 10 windows

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I think there is a bug in Windows 10 and fonts are too small or too big even when DPI scale is %100.

My question is, how can I reset the font size (ie. in registry)? Somehow they stuck and now %100 is not %100, the fonts are bigger or smaller at %100.

[image]

Comment: are you sure that is 100%? This looks like 125% scaling

Comment: That's the problem. It looks like %400 since it's %100.

Comment: post screenshots of the DPI settings from settings app